# How "i++" is more efficient than "i = i + 1"?

Tags: c

Is there is any difference between these two statements performance wise ?

```
i++;
i = i + 1;
```

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question.

Comment: ++i is most efficient, i++ returns a copy of i before incrementing the variable. Were ++i simple increments the variable and avoids the copy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on the optimisation. `i++` can, on most processors, be represented as a single machine language instruction. `i = i + 1`, on the other hand, could be represented by up to four: load `i`, load `1`, add, store to `i`; although, even a middling smart compiler should be able to recognise it can rewrite it into the former.

Answer (score 0):

no, there is no difference. The compiler will compile these into the same assembly

Comment: Yes, Amadan's answer is more complete and correct. I did assume that the code was compiled with optimization enabled.

Comment: @DividebyZero: Well, to be honest, today in the age of LLVM and stuff, there actually is no difference, I believe. It's just that I don't automatically assume C = modern C :) (I have some acquaintances who still work on 25-year-old Sun boxen)